# Does Atom provide a Macro functionality like Notepad++ has?

Tags: notepad++, macros, atom-editor

I am thinking about switching from Notepad++ to Atom. Does Atom provide a Macro functionality like Notepad++ has?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you mean the `Ctrl + Shift + R`, `Ctrl + Shift + P` macro recording and play in Notepad++ (how much I love these!), then Atom does have it.

The `atom-keyboard-macros` does the same thing albeit with some complicated chords.

I am on v0.11.0 (Nov 2017) of the plugin and on Mac so YMMV. Things look good so far to me, however I haven't been very successful in unmapping these shortcuts and making them similar to the ones in Notepad++.

`Ctrl + Shift + R` - which used to toggle record and stop record in Notepad++ is handled by `Ctrl + X; Ctrl + (` followed by `Ctrl + X; Ctrl + )`, not very efficient!

`Ctrl + Shift + P` is handled by `Ctrl + x; e`

See the shortcuts section under https://atom.io/packages/atom-keyboard-macros

Hope that helps..

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

#### Does Atom provide a Macro functionality?

Yes.

> **The atom-macros package**
>
> Makes Atom really hackable. Quickly, without writing a package...
>
> Fast and dynamic extension of Atom's command palette. Adds all methods defined by you on this in the `.atom/macros.coffee` file as Atom commands:
>
> - They can be executed using the command palette
>     (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) as Macro: `<Your Method Name>`, or from the menu Packages > Macros> User-defined macros.
> - You can also add a shortcut in your `keymaps` file:
>
>   ```
>   'atom-workspace':
>     'ctrl-alt-shift-O': 'macros:openBrowser'
>   ```

Source [The atom-macros package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-macros)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there are two packages for that in Atom. One is is `atom-keyboard-macros` (4K downloads) which is barely usable, and another is `atom-macros` (1.5K downloads) which failed to even install on my system.... 
Obviously this is not the area which typical atom users are interested in.

Comment: Please be a bit more direct about your answer.  It seems you are simply answering the question indirectly by saying it isn't usable.

Comment: @Dale Well, it is hard to say that it does not provide that functionality at all, but it is definitely not on par with more mature editors. That is the point I was trying to make.

Comment: That's fair.  Understood.